# Can i redirect with htaccess based on server address?

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

i have 2 vps serving my domain using dns balancing.
i need to redirect all the traffic to the one server using .htaccess.

all solutions i have met are based on conditions which are examine HTTP_HOST
ex

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.domain.com
```

My problem is that i need to check server address, not the HTTP_HOST.
Is there any variable to htaccess providing that information?

PS I cannot use scripts right now, thats why i need htaccess.

ty

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Manual: https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#RewriteCond

```
RewriteCond %{SERVER_ADDR} = 1.2.3.4
```

Replace with the appropriate IP address, of course ;)